# Media Query for text-align: center

Tags: css, text, alignment, media-queries, center

I'm having some issues with a media query. I'm trying to center text for mobile devices only. I've added the following to my CSS, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

@media only screen and (max-width:500px){.category-compare {text-align:center;}}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your nesting is correct. Media queries are very pedantic.

Check your code for previous `text-align` rules on `.category-compare` and check how it is nested, i.e.: `.main-content .left-side .category-compare`. If it is nested like that, you will need to do the same nesting for your media query.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark, much appreciated.

Unfortunately I don't have any other code for .category-compare - it's my first entry for it.

Comment: I tell a lie. I have the Google Font Control CSS as follows:

.category-compare {font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'; font-size: 40px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 0.8;}

Comment: What type of element is `.category-compare` i.e: div, span etc

Comment: It's a span Mark. I have tried the following also, but no success:

@media only screen and (max-width:500px){span.category-compare {text-align:center;}}

Comment: That'll be why, span elements don't have full width, it's width is literally the width of its content, so centering the text won't do any good, apply a rule of `display: block` to it, if that messes up your design, try `display: inline-block`

Comment: Awesome - thank you Mark. Sorry for the rookie question but do I just add display: block or display: inline-block to the CSS edit please? Thanks!

Comment: No problem. And sorry I don't follow, do you mean do you add it to your main CSS for `.category-compare` or to the media query part for it?

Comment: My apologies - my poor explanation of my query. Exactly Mark, so for example, would I amend the CSS to the following?

@media only screen and (max-width:500px){.category-compare {display: block}}

Comment: Probably best to add it to your main CSS. However I can't see it doing any harm in your media query CSS

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `text-align:center;` to `text-align:center !important;`. This is forcefully text-align property.